# create .py files that will run through a specified python virtual enviroment while also importing other files by specified paths

Tags: python, linux, module, virtualenv

I am very new to linux in general and have been tasked with managing a server. 
Because of reasons, I had to create a python virtual environment under my user.

file directories as such:

```
~
    /python_venv
    /scripts
        /data_curation
            -master.py
            /mods
               -file1.py
               -file2.py
            /other
               -file3.py
        /otherscripts
            -file4.py
```

^basically the python venv is in the ~ directory. 
everything else is housed in scripts/data_curation
and scripts/otherscripts.

i was curious about TWO things. 
1) is there a way I can just run each file from command line without having to manually activate the python venv? for example, something like putting a line in the .py files that calls the venv on its own by specified path?

2) whats the easiest way to make sure each of these files all have access to one another? meaning if i wanted to import file3.py into file4.py, how would i go about that?

I have been trying to use importlib but i am getting this error:

```
(python) [user@server]$ python scripts/data_curation/mods/file1.py
scripts/data_curation/device_functions/epon_nokia.py
ModuleSpec(name='file3', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f66399f9a90>, origin='scripts/data_curation/other/file3.py')
__init__.py
scripts/data_curation/other/__init__.py
ModuleSpec(name='__init__', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f661a7242b0>, origin='scripts/data_curation/other/__init__.py')
__pycache__
scripts/data_curation/other/__pycache__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/data_curation/file1.py", line 21, in <module>
    module = imputil.module_from_spec(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 568, in module_from_spec
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

Comment: I don't understand your second question, I'm afraid; how did you use `importlib`?

Comment: here is how ive used import lib in the past, on a windows machine:
`for i in range(len(mods.names)):`
`    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(mods.names[i],mods.paths[i])`
`    Modules[mods.names[i]] = spec.loader.load_module()`
I use it to load module references into a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you can explicitly reference the Python executable in your venv:

```
python_venv/bin/python scripts/data/master.py
```

or change the shebang at the start of each script to point to the same place directly and then run with just `scripts/data/master.py` (although that hard-codes the location, which you probably don't want).

Comment: so on the note of the shebang.
I have:
`#! ~/python`.
i also tried:
`#! user/bin//python`
none of which seem to cause the file to automatically run with the venv.

Comment: Yes, I mean you would have to change that to `/home/user/python_venv/bin/python`.

Comment: do i need the #! before that? So when add the line without the #!, it seems to open the python interpretor. But the script is stuck on that until i exit it. If I do add the #!, I get this error: `[user@server ~]$ scripts/data_curation/master.py
-bash: scripts/data_curation/master.py: ~/python/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`